# Can callbacks be used with promises or is it one way or the other in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to NodeJs. I read [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/before-you-bury-yourself-in-packages-learn-the-node-js-runtime-itself-f9031fbd8b69) and found a question:

> Can callbacks be used with promises or is it one way or the other?

I searched the answer but it is not clear. So what is the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure they can, just call the callback as part of the `.then` / `.catch` chain. It can make sense when you would refactor older code, but don't want to change the full library. In the end, promises is just a cleaner way of working with callbacks

Comment: Technically, promises use callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always turn a callback into a promise to make it cooperate with your other promises smoothly. Let's assume `asyncFunc` is a function that takes a callback. You can turn it into a promise this way:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    asyncFunc((error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            resolve(result);
        }
    }
});
```

Most libraries implementing promises offer a shortcut for the above code construct:

```
Promise.promisify(asyncFunc);
```